# How to reset animation in react-spring?

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-spring

**Intro:**

I'm trying to reset animation after some user activities(such as "clicking on close button", etc).

**Code:**

```
const animation = useSpring({
    from: {
      scale: 1
    },
    to: {
      scale: 1.15
    },
    config: {
      duration: 1000
    },
    loop: true
  })

const onClickHandler = () => {
  animation.reset() // Property 'reset' does not exist on type '{ scale: SpringValue<number>; }'
}
```

**Problem:**

Property 'reset' does not exist on type '{ scale: SpringValue; }'

1/ I've tried to check `reset` method. Documentation said it's done, but it's not. https://react-spring.dev/docs/advanced/spring-value#reset

2/ I've tried to use [this example](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/331), but it's not working in my case. The animation is not resetting to default state.

**Question:**

How can I reset `useSpring`(and `useTransition`) animation?

**Context:**

- "@react-spring/web": "^9.6.1"